# Postgresql : find size of all objects in a tablespace

Tags: postgresql

I am running out of space on my default tablespace.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_tablespace_size('pg_default'));
89 GB
(1 row)
```

However, if I calculate the pg_relation_size of all tables in this tablespace i only get 16GB

```
select pg_size_pretty(sum(sz)) 
from (
    select *,(pg_total_relation_size(tablename::varchar)) as sz 
    from pg_tables 
    where tablespace is null 
      and tablename not like 'pg_%' 
     and schemaname != 'information_schema' 
) as foo;

16 GB
(1 row)
```

So where is the rest?

I do calculate the index+data

Comment: That sounds like table bloat: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Show_database_bloat  You should also pass the `oid` to `pg_total_relation_size` otherwise this will give wrong results if you have the same table name in different schemas. You might also want to check the queries from here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage

Comment: You query does not include materialized views - do you use them?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple databases may use server's default tablespace. Check it with:

```
select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(oid))
from pg_database
union
select null, pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_database_size(oid)))
from pg_database;
```